# Quasar Framework: How to use a different icon set with QUploader

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, quasar-framework

Quasar's documentation is usually really good, so I was surprised to find no information for how to change the default icons in the QUploader component.

I'm using the `mdi-v5` icon set. When I load up the component, instead of a `plus` icon on top right, it just looks like this:

[image]

I've scoured the docs, but there doesn't seem to be any way to customise the icons on this particular component. Surely this can be done??

Comment: Show some code...

Comment: @MichalLevý Such as? I didn't deem there to be any appropriate code.

Comment: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/1222

Answer (score 0):

Use Slots:

> In the example below we’re showing the equivalent of the default
> header.

Check the Official Documentation, in the Custom Header you can customize the icon.
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/uploader#example--custom-header

**Edit:**
Looks like you have to change the Icon Set in the configuration file, here a video from Luke where shows the process,
https://quasarcast.com/quasar-getting-started/quasar-getting-started-guide-3-skeleton-part-1

Comment: I think there must be a general way to solve the issue. The need arises for other components soon or later. Your solution is pretty good for just one special component. Some others have no slot to customize e.g. q-select icon. Therefore a trick is needed to manipulate all default icons.

Comment: I did edit the answer with the "proper" way to change the icon libraries